# Getting Struts 1.3 to use Tiles 2.1.2+

Tags: java, spring, openshift, tiles, struts-1

I am in the process of migrating a Java web app that uses **Spring 2.5** (jdbc & aop) and **Struts 1.3.10** to OpenShift. This will entail upgrading Spring to 3.2(?) which uses Tiles 2.1.2+.

So, I want to stop using **struts-tiles** and start using **Apache Tiles** 2.1.2+ (maybe even 3.0.7).

Anyone done this before?

What 'listener' should I use?

What about the chainConfig (currently org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml in web.xml)?

Any advice would be much appreciated...

Answer (score -1):

did you check migration steps provided in : Migration from Struts-Tiles http://tiles.apache.org/framework/migration/ ?

it contains the steps to flow to passe from struts-tiles to apache tiles

> **Migration from Struts-Tiles**
>   This tutorial is intended to provide a help when migrating from the previous version of Tiles, known as Struts-Tiles.
>
> To use Tiles you need to put in your web application library directory:
>
> `tiles-api.jar`: it contains the API to manipulate and render Tiles.
>   `tiles-core.jar`: it contains the "engine" of Tiles, and the basic implementation of the APIs.
>   `tiles-servlet.jar`: it contains the servlet support in Tiles.
>   `tiles-jsp.jar`: it contains the JSP support to Tiles, i.e. JSP specific classes and the tag library.
>   `tiles-compat.jar`: it contains the compatibility layer of Tiles to support Struts-Tiles 1.x XML definition files.
>
> **Further steps**
>   [Tiles configuration files](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/migration/configuration.html): How to migrate Tiles configuration files, the file usually named `tiles-defs.xml`.
>   [Tiles JSP tags](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/migration/tags.html): How to migrate Tiles JSP tags, the `<tiles:...>` tags.
>   [Java APIs considerations](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/migration/apis.html): Some information and warnings on the different behaviour of the Tiles Java API.
>   [Tiles extensions](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/migration/extension.html): How to migrate Tiles extensions, with explanation of main changes in the code structure.

Comment: @baum-mit-augen I can't put all the steps and variants of the solution in the answer, how ever I made my best to make it clear.